# Scrape web application behind Azure Active Directory authentication with .NET HttpClient

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, dotnet-httpclient

I need to scrape a web page which is behind an Azure Active Directory authentication. When accessing the page via MS Edge it seems that Edge authenticates itself automatically from currently logged in user.
However as my application is not a browser but a console application I am unable to do this automatically. I would like to somehow pass the identity of the currently logged in user (who is a part of the Azure AD domain).
Any recommendations / ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Check this [MSdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions).